# How to fit divs/placeholders into a boostrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use this [grid/Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/) example as my grid layout for alot of charts I want to plot.

This is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o4678994/6/). In this example I am just using placeholders that would represent my charts. My qustion is how do I make the charts fit into these slots correctly?

I understand I could just change the size of the chart(`{width: 300, height: 240}`) or placeholder in this example. But I would like to do the opposite and be able to change the div container width `<div class="container">` to accomadate the size of the chart.

There is also the problem that this html/css adapts(is responsive) to the screen size, in that the placeholders would become stacked if the screen size gets narrower.

I understand this question may be a bit broad, But I would appreciate some pointers in this area if possible.

Comment: `.col-3` contains the rule `max-width: 25%`. You'll need to override that at least --> https://jsfiddle.net/6xqa9j2d/

Comment: tks. how do I catually control the width of this div `<div class="container">` so that all 4 placeholders will fit across the screen in the 1 row?

Comment: Do you want the placeholders to scale like this? https://jsfiddle.net/515ujavn/

Comment: yes tks, but then, if possible to be responsive(stack as the screen gets smaller) as well.

Comment: You may need to change column to `.col-sm-3`. --> https://jsfiddle.net/515ujavn/6/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap4 add .img-fluid  or .img-responsive for bootstrap3 class for img

Comment: tks this works for images `<div class="col-3"><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x240" class="img-fluid"></a></div>` I was more thinking of anything inside the div to fit e.g. another div. tks though!

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aazk7cxn/1/)

To make the columns stack at different breakpoints you can use the relevant modifying class.

For example:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-m-4">
  <a href="https://placeholder.com">
    <img src="">
  </a>
</div>
```

This creates a column that will default to 12 column widths (i.e the full width of the grid). At small screen sizes, columns become 6 column widths, at medium sizes 4... You can choose different numbers as you need. You can also add a class for larger screens, e.g. `col-lg-3` ([Grid docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/))

The second thing you need to do is make the images responsive. You should be able to add the class `.img-responsive` to your images. ([From the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images)). However this class doesn't seem to be in the CSS you've provided. I've added it manually to the fiddle.

Comment: justa quick comment, I don't think all 4 place holders can be shown in the 1 row as the screen gets wider- at least as wide as the jsfiddle will allow.

Comment: Yes, the jsfiddle (on my screen) won't expand enough to fit them all in. You can change the classes to `col-12 col-sm-4 col-m-3` for example

Answer (score 0):

Apply `style="max-width:100%;"` in your all image tag. That will fit your image in proper column of bootstrap grid.